# How to render children into specified named slot in VueJs?

Tags: vue.js, render, vuejs2, createelement, slot

Refer to the code below, currently all the children were rendered inside the default slot even though the slot name is given.

Not sure whether vue createElement function supports named slot?

```
@Component({
    props:[]
})
export class TestComponent extends Widget{
    items:any[];
    render(h:any){
        const rootcmp = {
            template:`<div>
                Temp:<slot name="temp"></slot>
                Default:<slot></slot>
            </div>`
            , data:()=>{
                return {};
            }
        }
        const cmp = {
            template:'<div slot="default">This is child</div>'
            , data:()=>{
                return {};
            }
        }
        const cmp2 = {
            template:'<div slot="temp">This is child</div>'
            , data:()=>{
                return {};
            }
        }
        return h(rootcmp, [h(cmp), h(cmp2)]);
    }
}
```

**Current behavior:**

```
<div>
Temp:Default:
<div>This is child</div>
<div>This is child</div>
</div>
```

**Expected behavior:**

```
<div>
Temp:
<div>This is child</div>
Default:
<div>This is child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ive been struggling getting 'h(COMP, null, { default: 90=>..., otherSlots: .()=>...}` working but vuejs isnt replacing the parent slots with the content

Comment: Confirmed vue2 v Vue3 issue for me:
vue2:  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html 
the children params doesnt accept object notation
vue3: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/render-function.html#h-arguments
the children param has object support HTH

Answer (score 1):

It sure does, in your options object, try `{slot:'slot-name'}`